# c++ 'undefined reference to' error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm having one of those "undefined reference to " errors when compiling a c++ program. I know this is common pitfall, but so far was unable to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the relevant code. Ex1Two_Sum.h:

```
#ifndef EX1TWO_SUM_H
#define EX1TWO_SUM_H

#include <vector>
using namespace std;

namespace ddc {
class Ex1Two_Sum
{
   public:
     void f();
   protected:
   private:
};
}

#endif
```

Ex1Two_Sum.cpp:

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace ddc {
class Ex1Two_Sum {
public:

  void f(){
    cout << "works" << endl;
  }
};
}
```

And finally, main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Ex1Two_Sum.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace ddc;

int main()
{
  Ex1Two_Sum ex1;
  ex1.f();
  return 0;
}
```

I compile as follows:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -c Ex1Two_Sum.cpp 
g++ -std=c++11 -c main.cpp 
g++ Ex1Two_Sum.o main.o
```

yielding the  following message:

```
main.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `ddc::Ex1Two_Sum::f()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your source file redefines the whole class, with an inline function definition, when it just needs to provide a non-inline function definition.

```
#include "Ex1Two_Sum.h"

void ddc::Ex1Two_Sum::f() {
    std::cout << "should work\n";
}
```

Also, please don't put `using namespace std;` in a header. Not everyone wants the global namespace polluted in [potentially surprising](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721) ways.

Comment: Yeah. works now -- needed to include iostream to compile. On a related note: would you say this is the usual way to define/use classes in c++? I mean, to have class specification in a .h file, and then a separate file simply implementing the functions?

Comment: @nmpg: Yes, that's the usual way to do it. The alternative is to define it all in a header, which is sometimes appropriate (and usually required when defining templates) but can lead to excessive dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

First, which line of the command throws that error?

Second, I think you forgot to include the `Ex1Two_Sum.h` in the `Ex1Two_Sum.cpp`

Third you need to change `class .......` in `Ex1Two_Sum.cpp` to:

```
void Ex1Two_Sum::f(){...}
```